# How can I write in multiple files at once using 'cat'?

Tags: bash, cat, echo, printf

This question is kind of related to my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/723668).

This is the output of `tree`:

```
[xyz@localhost Semester1]$ tree
.
├── Eng
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── IT
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── IT_workshop
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── LA
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── OS
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── OS_lab
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── Psy
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
├── Python
│   ├── credits
│   ├── links
│   └── notes
└── Python_lab
    ├── credits
    ├── links
    └── notes

9 directories, 27 files
```

Now I want to mention the number of credits each course is having in the credits file of the respective folder using `cat`.

For example, this is the number of credits each course is having:

| Course name | Credits |
| --- | --- |
| Eng | 2 |
| LA | 3 |
| Python | 3 |
| OS | 3 |
| IT | 3 |
| IT_workshop | 1 |
| Python_lab | 1 |
| OS_lab | 1 |
| Psy | 2 |

For adding credits details in Eng/credits, I need to run this:

```
cat >> Eng/credits
```

and type the number of credits (i.e., 2) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I have to do the same step for the remaining 8 files and it seems like tedious work. Is there any way to do all of this at once using `cat`?

I spoke to some friends who are knowledgeable about Bash, and they said that it is better to use `echo` or `printf` in my case. Why is that so?

---

I'm expecting to do this:

- In the Eng/credits file, I want the number 2 to be written.
- In the LA/credits file, I want the number 3 to be written.
- In the Python/credits file, I want the number 3 to be written.
- In the OS/credits file, I want the number 3 to be written.
- In the IT/credits file, I want the number 3 to be written.
- In the IT_workshop/credits file, I want the number 1 to be written.
- In the Python_lab/credits file, I want the number 1 to be written.
- In the OS_lab/credits file, I want the number 1 to be written.
- In the Psy/credits file, I want the number 2 to be written.

After reading [Hack Saw](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7503/hack-saw)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723774), I tried this command:

```
echo {2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2} >> {Eng/credits,LA/credits,Python/credits,OS/credits,IT/credits,IT_workshop/credits,Python_lab/credits,OS_lab/credits,Psy/credits}
```

but it didn't work as I expected it to:

```
bash: {Eng/credits,LA/credits,Python/credits,OS/credits,IT/credits,IT_workshop/credits,Python_lab/credits,OS_lab/credits,Psy/credits}: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: Is pure `cat` a necessity? If you already have the data in a CSV-like format, many other tools would be much more handy.

Comment: @FelixJN This question was actually there in my assignment and they asked me to use `cat`. But I would love to see people solve this issue using other commands. I didn't store the data in CSV-like format, but if it's needed, I'm willing to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Cat is used to output whole files. 
Its operands (non-option parameters) are files. 
When you do `cat >> foo`, you are redirecting the file stdout to `foo`.

Echo and printf take immediate data.

```
echo 2 >> foo
```

... puts a 2 into the file `foo`.

Printf gives you a way to add extra formatting onto things,
is more standardized,
and is potentially safer in the face of unknown data.

Comment: *It's parameters are files* technically speaking `cat` may receive non-file options such as `-v` or `--help`

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't be able to do it with cat with any method less tedious
than the manual method you show in the question. 
Try this:

```
while read course credit; do
  echo $credit >> $course/credits
done <<EOF
Eng 2
LA 3
Python 3
OS 3
IT 3
IT_workshop 1
Python_lab 1
OS_lab 1
Psy 2
EOF
```

From the [bash man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> `read`
> `[-ers]`
> `[-a aname]`
> `[-d delim]`
> `[-i text]`
> `[-n nchars]`
> `[-N nchars]`
> `[-p prompt]`
> `[-t timeout]`
> `[-u fd]`
> `[name ...]`
>
>   One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor
>   *`fd`*
>   supplied as an argument to the
>   **`-u`**
>   option,
>   split into words as described above under
>   **Word Splitting**
>   ,
>   and the first word is  assigned  to  the
>   first
>   *`name`*
>   ,  the  second word to the second
>   *`name`*
>   ,
>   and so on.  If there are more words than names,
>   the remaining words and their intervening delimiters
>   are assigned to the last
>   *`name`*
>   .  If there  are  fewer  words
>   read  from  the input stream than names, the remaining names are assigned empty values.  The characters in
>   **`IFS`**
>   are used to split the line into words using the same rules the shell  uses  for  expansion  (described
>   above  under
>   **Word  Splitting**
>   ).  The backslash character (
>   **`\`**
>   ) may be used to remove any special meaning for
>   the next character read and for line continuation.  Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:
>   ︙

The `read course credit` command will assign the first word on each line to  the variable `course` and then the rest of the line (a number in this case) gets assigned to the variable `credit`.

Also from the man page:

> **Here Documents**
>
>   This  type  of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only
>   *`delimiter`*
>   (with no trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used as  the  standard input
>   (or file descriptor
>   *`n`*
>   if
>   *`n`*
>   is specified) for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```

In this case 'word' and 'delimiter' are `EOF` and the 'here-document' is the data. You can replace everything from `<<EOF` onwards with a file containing the data and redirect stdin from that; e.g., `<data.txt`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. It would be great if you can explain a bit abut what your code does or how it works. P.S. I'm a beginner.

Comment: The `<<EOF` is a Here document feeding the lines to the `while read` loop.  [3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)